# How to detect numbers in a picture?

Tags: php, ocr

Is there any php class that detects numbers in a picture? for example detecting a license plate in a picture. 
I couldn't find any usfull information in google search.

Comment: You probably want to try OCR library

Comment: I've suggested this Q is put on hold as "request for library", but it may be [a duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008814/recognizable-numbers-using-php) anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**phpOCR**](http://phpocr.sourceforge.net/) is an Optical Character Recognition system written in PHP. It can be used in automated scripts as well as web interface. Works best for small images like numeric SMS/email authorization codes, bar-code numbers and others.

http://phpocr.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Have a look to this library: [phpOCR](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html)

Comment: That's right typing the 2 words "OCR" and "PHP" into a search engine was the problem.

Comment: Yes, because OP didn't know exact term: OCR. I understand it.